# PHP - Appended html string being cut off

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templating

I'm generating some html to be used with the MPDF php library for generating a PDF. But when I create some HTML with php which has a loop inside it, it cuts of the beginning of the string, here's my code:

```
$page = "<div class='A4'><h1>Test: lookbook</h1><p>";
$page .= $date;

$page .= "</p><div class='items'>";

while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    $page .= "<img src='";
    $page .= get_field('product_image')['url'];
    $page .= "'>";
}
$page .= "</div></div><div class='footer'>A Story in every gemstone</div>";

echo $page;
```

Running the above code returns:

```
1<img src='urltoimage'></div></div><div class='footer'>A Story in every gemstone</div>
```

So it looks like everything before the while loop is being cut out.

Comment: Are you sure $date contains a date string ?

Comment: This is what date is set to $date = date("l");

Comment: Try displaying date on its own, add "[{$date}]".   Are you sure "the_post" isn't outputting anything? Change $page to $output

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser it was me taking out some sensitive information from the output, but I didn't remove it from the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$page` is a Wordpress global variable that exists within The Loop.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

> WordPress-specific global variables are used throughout WordPress code for various reasons. Almost all data that WordPress generates can be found in a global variable.
>
> While inside the loop, these globals are set, containing information about the current post being processed.
>
> ...
>
> $page (int) The page of the current post being viewed. Specified by the query var page.